# How can I pass class variable as a method's parameter in c++?

Tags: c++, class

I'd like to pass a class's variable as a parameter to one of that class's methods, but I get an error that says "A reference to a non-static member must be relative to a specific object".

```
class myClass
{
private:
  int x = 1;
public:
  void func(int pos = x)
  {
    //whatever
  }
};
```

I'd like to make it so that if a parameter is passed when the method is called then that's the one used to initialize `pos`, otherwise x is used.

I tried looking for solutions but wasn't able to find anything. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Overloads: One taking one (non-default) argument; One taking no arguments, calling the first and passing `x`.

Comment: To receive a good solution you should explain: Why you need this. IMO best solution is to drop default value and provide an overload.

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to search and then research and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ you cannot use a non-static member as a default parameter.

You probably want this:

```
class myClass
{
private:
  static int x;
public:
  void func(int pos = x)
  {
    //whatever
  }
};

int myClass::x = 1;
```

or this:

```
class myClass
{
private:
  int x = 1;
public:
  void func(int pos)
  {
    //whatever
  }

  void func()
  {
    int y = x;
    // whatever
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75995750/how-can-i-pass-class-variable-as-a-methods-parameter-in-c#comment134034496_75995750) suggest, you can do function overloading. Define one function taking one parameter and one taking no parameters, calling the first and passing the class's variable, in this case, `x`.

It would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass
{
private:
    int x = 1;
public:
    void func(int pos)
    {
        std::cout << pos;
    }
    void func()
    {
        func(x);
    }
};
int main()
{
    myClass my_class;
    my_class.func(); // no parameters 
    std::cout << '\n';
    my_class.func(2); // one parameter
}
```

The program prints:

```
1
2
```

[Link](https://godbolt.org/z/3Te84hz5z).